# Adding least vector to turn sum of vectors by given angle

Tags: vectors

Let's take a classic 2-dimensiona vector addition:

[image]

Given vector $ \vec{a} $ and angle $\phi$ I need to find $ \vec{b} $ of least possible magnitude such that vector $ \vec{c} = \vec{a}+ \vec{b} $  is at angle $\phi$ to $ \vec{a} $; I don't care about magnitude of $ \vec{c} $.

(actual practical problem I face, optimal angle of burn of a rocket engine to change rocket trajectory by given angle at moment's notice in Kerbal Space Program. I found how to retain magnitude $ | \vec{c} | = |\vec{a}| $ but I'm really not sure how to approach optimizing it when the resultant magnitude is insignificant and I just need to change direction for least cost, simply accepting whatever speed results from that.)

Comment: Hint: $b\perp c$

Comment: $b=|\sin \theta| Ra$, where $R$ is a rotation of $\pi-\theta$.

Comment: This is equivalent to finding the closest point to $c$ on the line defined by $a$.

Comment: @Exodd: Actually your hint solves my practical problem. Point my craft perpendicular to where I want to go, burn until direction is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that
$$
\|b\|^2 = \|c-a\|^2 = \|a\|^2 + \|c\|^2 - 2\|a\|\|c\|\cos \phi
$$
$\|a\|$ and $\theta$ are fixed, so we can only change $\|c\|$. We can find the minimum of $\|b\|$ by deriving in $\|c\|$ and putting the derivative to zero:
$$
2\|c\|-2\|a\|\cos \phi = 0
$$
$$
\|c\| = \|a\| \cos \phi
$$
$$
\|b\|^2 = \|a\|^2\sin^2\phi
$$
so you obtain that $b\perp c$ since
$$
\|a\|^2 = \|c-b\|^2 = \|c\|^2 + \|b\|^2 - 2 c\cdot b  = \|a\|^2 - 2c\cdot b
$$
$$\implies c\cdot b =0$$

Comment: While Ross's answer is more brief and looks quite elegant, your is easier to use in practical computation. (btw, it may seem obvious, but besides $b\perp c$,  to make the answer complete, $ \|b\| = \|a\|\sin\phi $ ).

Answer (score 1):

You want to project $\vec a$ onto the direction $\vec c$.  That projection is $(\vec a \cdot \vec c)\vec c$.  Then $\vec b = \vec a -(\vec a \cdot \vec c)\vec c$